# Как получить в переменную реакцию на которую нажал пользователь discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

Как получить в переменную реакцию на которую нажал пользователь discord.py? Например, при нажатии на одну из 5 реакций, мне нужно получить пользователя, и ту реакцию на которую он нажал. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая замечательная вещь, как [**документация**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). В ней есть информация про абсолютно все объекты библиотеки `discord-py`, их свойства и методы.

На StakOverflow не принято отвечать на вопросы тех, кто даже не попытался что-то сделать самостоятельно, однако, я готов помочь, поэтому я вас очень прошу, чтобы не задавать подобных вопросов, ознакомьтесь с кратким [**руководством по использованию документации**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/using_docs.md).

---

В данном случае, вам всего лишь нужно написать в поиске слово `reaction` и изучить материал по обработчику событий [`on_raw_reaction_add(payload)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.on_raw_reaction_add), в который передается объект [`payload`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.RawReactionActionEvent), из которого можно получить вот эти объекты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`member` - участник

`emoji` - объект реакции

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print(payload.member)
    print(str(payload.emoji))
```